# Why didn't this def function work in python?

Tags: python, function

First one same output
input: abc => output : abc

latter one works properly
input : abc => output : cde

What is the difference between two? I couldn't figure it out.

```
**First one**

def encrypt(a, b):
    for n in a:
        n = alphabet[alphabet.index(n)+b]
    print(f"The encoded text is {a}")

encrypt(text,shift)

**Second one**

def encrypt(a, b):
    new =""
    for n in a:
        new += alphabet[alphabet.index(n)+b]
    print(f"The encoded text is {new}")

encrypt(text,shift)
```

Comment: Your post title seems completely unrelated to the question in your post. Please [edit] your post to fix that. Also, please fix the post itself: that is _not_ valid Python code, so at the very least put your text where regular text goes, outside the code block, and properly indent and format your python code so it's proper [mcve] code. And remember to (re)read the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) to make sure your post follows those.

Comment: In the first one, you print `a`, which is never changed.  In the second one, you print `new`, which *is* changed.  Why would you have expected the first one to do anything?

Comment: I think he expects the `n` in the first code to be a reference and `=` changes the value of the reference. This is not the case, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the comments everyone. This is the first time I posted question. I learned a lot next time I will check the title and contents more carefully. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the first one, you `return a` at the end in the string in the end, so basically, you get the inputs process them to outputs, but then return the inputs. The second one is the right way to do it.

PS: Please use real variable names. It helps yourself when your programs get bigger and other people that want to understand your code without analyzing it first.